# MySQL: Optimizing/restructuring a big table

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, database-design, query-optimization

We have a table with below details in MySQL 5.7 (will move on 8.0 soon!)

1. Records:  948 283 303
2. Total size: 817 GB
3. Data size: 310 GB
4. Index size: 506 GB

What should be the approach to optimize or restructure this table?

**Current problem:**

1. Query with multiple joins for one day is taking around 5 hours to finish
2. No partition in use
3. Index size is too large compared to the data size and there is no duplicate/redundant composite index present.

**Solution:**

1. Get rid of historical data, but there is data from 2021 which is of just last three years and this data is needed for operational purpose.
2. Partition daily/monthly
3. Create yearly table with partitions

Are the solutions correct? any disadvantages to move on with above solution? Also happy to hear other suggestions.

Comment: good indexes are almost always a better choice than partitioning.  but there is no one size fits all answer.  with good indexing and queries written to take advantage of it, keeping historic data should be possible without undue effect on performance.

Comment: please do edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `explain select ...` for the query in question and `show create table ...` for each table it uses.

Comment: "Index size is to large" - too large for what?  what is the problem here?  having a variety of queries can mean having quite a few indexes and a lot of space taken up by them, this isn't necessarily a bad thing

Comment: It is pretty common in my experience that the index storage may be _larger_ than the data storage.

Comment: Please post the query that is taking 5 hours to finish.  And the SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; for each table used in the query.

Answer (score 0):

- `PARTITION BY TO_DAYS(...)` allows rapid purging of "old" data.
- Having too many or too few partitions is inefficient.  For what you describe, I recommend monthly partitions.
- See [*Partition*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) for more discussion of how to establish and maintain partitions.
- The indexes revisited.
- *Usually* the partition key, when needed, should be late in any secondary `INDEX`.
- `FOREIGN` and `UNIQUE` keys are not supported.  (By now you have debugged your app enough so those are an unnecessary burden.)
- It will take a long time to add partitioning,  `ADD PARTITIONING` copies the entire table and rebuilds the indexes.  Since you desire to purge some of the data now, I suggest copying the data to *keep* as being faster and effective, something like:

  ```
  CREATE TABLE with_partitions (
      ...
      PRIMARY KEY(...)  -- see link
      -- no secondary keys yet
      PARTITION BY RANGE TO_DAYS(col) ( ... ) -- see link
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

  INSERT INTO with_partitions
      SELECT ...
          FROM main
          WHERE the_date >= '2021-01-01';  -- just the data to keep

  ALTER TABLE with_partitions
      ADD INDEX(...),...;

  -- test the code; revise indexes if needed; etc.

  RENAME TABLE main TO old,
               with_partitions TO main;
  -- more testing

  DROP TABLE old; -- see below if you need to keep the old data
  ```
- You said "get rid of historical data".  If you really meant to move it to somewhere else, then perhaps you should keep `old` and worry about removing the *new* data from it.  Let me know if you want to discuss that further.
- I will probably have more advice if I can see the current `CREATE TABLEs` and important queries (such as the 5-hour one).
- As the link discusses, periodically execute `DROP PARTITION` and `REORGANIZE PARTITION future INTO p{next_month}, future`.
- If the data is sensor/stocks/tracking/etc, see https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_sensor